# How to use a template and variable name to count some values of a specific node in xsl

Tags: templates, variables, xslt

I use a template as

```
 <xsl:template name="myTemplate">
```

and I need to count the amount of level nodes whose values are "ON" and "OFF".

The final report that I want to have:

```
this file contains three "ON" values and two "OFF" values.
```

Look at a part of my xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml:stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='view.xsl'?>
<DOC>
<show>VIEW<show/>
<Entry>
 <light>ae</light>
 <level>ON</level>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <light>by</light>
 <level>OFF</level>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <light>ac</light>
 <level>OFF</level>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <light>pc</light>
 <level>ON</level>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <light>tc</light>
 <level>ON</level>
</Entry>
```

Thank for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These simple XPaths will do the trick:

```
count(/*/*/level[. = 'ON'])
```

and

```
count(/*/*/level[. = 'OFF'])
```

**For verification, when this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:text>The number of ON nodes is: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/level[. = 'ON'])"/>
    <xsl:text/>
    <xsl:text>The number of OFF nodes is: </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="count(/*/*/level[. = 'OFF'])"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**...is applied against the provided XML:**

```
<DOC>
  <show>VIEW</show>
  <Entry>
    <light>ae</light>
    <level>ON</level>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <light>by</light>
    <level>OFF</level>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <light>ac</light>
    <level>OFF</level>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <light>pc</light>
    <level>ON</level>
  </Entry>
  <Entry>
    <light>nc</light>
    <level>ON</level>
  </Entry>
</DOC>
```

**...the wanted result is produced:**

```
The number of ON nodes is: 3
The number of OFF nodes is: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is to count and spell out the numbers i.e **two, three**. Please find below XSLT and the list of format values to be used in the link given.

```
    <?xml version='1.0'?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="DOC">
    <xsl:text>this file contains </xsl:text> 
    <xsl:number value="count(descendant::level[(.)='ON'])" format="w"/>
    <xsl:text> "ON" values and </xsl:text>
    <xsl:number value="count(descendant::level[(.)='OFF'])" format="w"/>
    <xsl:text> "OFF" values.</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Please refer the below documentation for format:
http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-number